# Codebuild: pull access denied

Tags: docker, aws-codebuild

I set up a codebuild for a python project with dependencies that takes to long to build. So I enabled artifact cache for docker layers. This works fine but only last for a short while and will invalidate cache for builds 15mins apart. Another solution I thought of was to pull the docker image on `pre_build` step but it doesn't seem to work. My buildspec:

```yaml
version: 0.2

env:
  secrets-manager:
    DOCKERHUB_ID: arn:aws:secretsmanager:■■■■■■:■■■■■■:■■■■■■:■■■■■■/■■■■■■:■■■■■■
    DOCKERHUB_TOKEN: arn:aws:secretsmanager:■■■■■■:■■■■■■:■■■■■■:■■■■■■/■■■■■■:■■■■■■
phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Logging in to Amazon ECR...
      - aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com
      - echo Logging in to Docker Hub...
      - echo $DOCKERHUB_TOKEN | docker login -u $DOCKERHUB_ID --password-stdin
      - docker pull $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com/$IMAGE_REPO_NAME || true
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - echo Building the Docker image on branch $CODEBUILD_WEBHOOK_HEAD_REF ...
      - touch .env
      - echo $ENV_PREFIX$IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG
      - docker build --cache-from $IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG --build-arg BUILD_SECRET_KEY=$SECRET_KEY -t $IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG -f docker/django/Dockerfile .
      - docker tag $ENV_PREFIX$IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com/$IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
      - echo Pushing the Docker image...
      - docker push $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com/$IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG
      - IMAGE_DIFINITION_APP="{\"name\":\"${CONTAINER_NAME}\",\"imageUri\":\"${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}.dkr.ecr.${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}.amazonaws.com/${IMAGE_REPO_NAME}:${IMAGE_TAG}\"}"
      - echo "[${IMAGE_DIFINITION_APP}]" > imagedefinitions.json
artifacts:
  files: imagedefinitions.json
```

I can successfully pull the image on `pre_build` but on the `build` step it gives me this error

```
#7 ERROR: pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed
```

The role I'm using already grants all privilege to ECR. Is there any other permission I'm missing?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a while to understand what went wrong but instead of:

```
 - docker build --cache-from $IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG --build-arg BUILD_SECRET_KEY=$SECRET_KEY -t $IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG -f docker/django/Dockerfile .
```

The registry name should be added before the repo name otherwise it will search docker hub instead of ecr:

```
 - docker build --cache-from $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com/$IMAGE_REPO_NAME --build-arg BUILD_SECRET_KEY=$SECRET_KEY -t $IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG -f docker/django/Dockerfile .
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look here:
[ECR polices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/repository-policy-examples.html)

Maybe you did not add permission in ECR policy.